# Is it allowed to force users to Subscribe via Free Trial AutoRenewable Subscription, or else, cant use the App at all?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Let's say once you install the app and open it for the first time.
You are presented with a PayWall, that you cant skip.
In order to use the app, you have to Subscribe via a FREE TRIAL Subscription.
Once the free trial ends it will automatically charge the user for the Subscription price.
Unless they cancel it before, making the app useless forever until they decide to pay the Subscription.

Does Apple allow that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Apple's website about [business models](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/business-models/) states the following about the `freemium` model:</strike>

> [It offers] the option to pay to enhance or customize the experience.

Therefore, I don't think that Apple will allow you to implement a `freemium` app without providing actually free content.

The auto-renewal of the free trial into a paid subscription is the "normal" behavior of Apple's free trial.

**Update 2024**

Apple has removed the part mentioned above from the documentation. Maybe this is allowed now or always has been, and Apple removed that to prevent confusion.

Comment: I am trying hard to find more evidence to support this answer, but investigating Apple official docs doesn't help much. Having said that, THERE IS THIS here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#attracting-subscribers that hints at the first option (of the three presented) being the hard paywall - and, further down, also lists some requirements (Subscription name and duration, and the content or services provided during the subscription period, A way for current subscribers to sign in or restore purchases, Full renewal price, shown clearly and prominently ...)

Comment: Also, the Apple App Store Review Guidelines don't mention anything like a hard paywall or it being unacceptable anywhere.

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/in-app-purchase#Autorenewable-subscriptions

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. I didn't mean to imply that it's forbidden. My understanding of that section, in the previous documentation, was that Apple mandates freemium apps to genuinely offer free content. It seems there have been updates to that document in the past three years.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of applications are doing this, the most famous one is probably Disney+. No (more) free trial, they ask you to register then subscribe.